# CSS background-image linking from inside Wordpress custom plugin php file

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image

I'm trying to use CSS background-image url('') link in my Wordpress plugin php file.  None of the images are showing and I'm not sure how to make it work.  It's for a client so I need the images to be able to be installed along with the plugin, not manually placed anywhere in the theme folder.

I've tried putting images in the theme folder but it still doesn't work.  I've tried linking to the url by storing it in a variable ($url).

```
 php:
 $url1 = 'image.png';

 css: (in same php document)
 .ch-img-2 {
background: white url('<?php echo $url2 ?>') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
 }

 also tried: 

 .ch-img-1 {
background: white url('<?php image.png ?>') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
```

Comment: Have you already tried using `plugins_url()` or `plugin_dir_url() . $filename`? That is the recommended way to retrieve the public filepath of a plugin asset, such as an image included with the plugin - see [this docs page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories). Also, '<?php image.png ?>' is invalid - `'<?php echo "image.png" ?>' would make sense if you trying to echo the filename string.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried but still not working.

Comment: .ch-img-1 {
  background: white url("<?php plugins_url( 'JPMorgan-Chase-Logo.png', __FILE__ )?>") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

Comment: I just need to load a background image using CSS that's embedded inside the main plugin PHP file.

Comment: You're missing an "echo" again, and it should be `__FILE__` - that should be `.ch-img-1 { background: white url("<?php echo plugins_url( 'JPMorgan-Chase-Logo.png',__FILE__ )?>") no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center; }`. You might want to take a look at these existing SO questions - [link1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60230/how-to-call-images-from-your-plugins-image-folder), [link2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up putting the CSS in its own file and then loading the background image normally.  I then enqueued the CSS file in my PHP file instead, thus avoiding the issue entirely.  Also cleaner.  Apparently calling the image file inside CSS that's embedded in the PHP would require an absolute URL which wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

From WP forums:

URLs in CSS files are relative to the CSS file and not the page URL.
But URLs in CSS that is inline (like in a  tag or even a style attribute are relative to the page URL.
So your plugin should put the CSS in a file and put the images relative to that, and then enqueue the style file only on pages where it is needed. If you don’t, you’ll have to generate the absolute URL and put it in the CSS that is inline.